# ChartJS - Bottom labels displayed vertically

Tags: charts, chart.js

I would like to ask how can I position bottom labels using ChartJS library to display them like on the image below:

[image]

I tried to find it in official docs, but without the luck.

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the xAxe ticks attribute, you can edit the `userCallback` property to change what is displayed on your labels. Furthermore, if you return an array of strings, every string will be displayed with line breaks.

So if you combine these two informations, you'll get the following :

```js
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                userCallback: function(tick, value, ticks) {
                    // `ticks` is the default display
                    // `.split("")` makes it an array of every character
                    return tick.split("");
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

You can see a working example [on this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aznupqqk/) and here is its result :

[image]